# Why a Vector3 has to be public or serialized to set it's value from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

Anyone care to explain why the `direction = bulletDirection;` only works when `direction` is public or `[SerializeField] private`?

I have `Shot()` on another script and i use it to set the `direction`.

```
private void Shot(){

    GameObject bullet = bulletPrefab;

    // Set Facing Side and Instantiate the Bullet
    if (activePlayerController.facingSide == PlayerController.FacingSide.Right) {
        bullet.GetComponent<BulletController> ().SetDirection (Vector3.right);
    } else if (activePlayerController.facingSide == PlayerController.FacingSide.Left) {
        bullet.GetComponent<BulletController> ().SetDirection (Vector3.left);
    }
    Instantiate (bullet, activePlayer.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, bulletsParent.transform);
}
```

But the `direction`is only set to `bulletDirection` when it is public or `[SerializeField] private`. When private it is always `Vector3.zero`.

```
[SerializeField] private Vector3 direction;

void FixedUpdate () {
    transform.Translate (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void SetDirection(Vector3 bulletDirection) {
    direction = bulletDirection;
}
```

Comment: Because the UnityEngine Vector3 type is a struct, and in C# you can't modify struct values directly. This is because structs are passed by vaule, so you're not getting the actual object, but a copy of it.

Comment: @Samssonart not true, invoking SetDirection() above will set direction to bulletDirection even if bulletDirection is a copy

Comment: Gerte, are you sure SetDirection() is invoked? it is very much possible it was never invoked, and direction is not Vector3.zero only because u set it in the inspector(which is only possible if it is serialized/public)

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask in the comments, but I haven't got the rep yet. So, what I'd suggest is to take a look at all the times "direction" is updated.

First though, when you instantiate a new item, the Awake() method is invoked, although Start() isn't until just before the next frame update. So, in between these times, any code that runs in Awake() and Start() could potentially have an effect on your initialisation process.

One way to determine the exact values and points in your code that update the "direction" value is to modify the direction to a property instead, and check the stack trace at each modification. You'd do this with the following code:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
#endif

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _direction = Vector3.None;
    public Vector3 direction
    {
        get
        {
            return _direction;
        }
        set
        {
            _direction = value;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ( "direction updated.\n" );
            StackTrace trace = new StackTrace ( true );
            for ( int i = 0; i < trace.FrameCount; i++ ) // You could use "for ( int i = 1; ... ", after you get the hang of it.
            {
                StackFrame sf = trace.GetFrame ( i );
                sb.AppendLine ( $"[{value}] {sf.GetMethod ( )} : {sf.GetFileName ( )} ({sf.GetFileLineNumber ( )})" );
            }
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log ( sb.ToString ( ) );
#endif
        }
    }
}
```